# rewriting a table/data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe, rewriting

Here is an example of my data set:

Sensor   ----      Time(GMT)    -----      Temperature (°C)

1 -------           24/06/2002 05:02:01   ---   33.855

2 -------          24/06/2002  05:02:01   ---   33.827

3 -------         24/06/2002  05:02:01    ---  33.104

4     -------      24/06/2002  05:02:01   ---   33.787

1       -------    24/06/2002  05:02:02   ---   33.609

2     -------      24/06/2002  05:02:02   ---   33.609

3     -------      24/06/2002  05:02:02   ---   33.610

4       -------    24/06/2002  05:02:02   ---   33.608

To be able to work with it I have to rewrite this dataset, so that it looks like this:

Time      ----------------------             Sensor1   -    Sensor2    -  Sensor3     -Sensor4

24/06/2002  05:02:01   -- 33.855   --      33.827    --    33.104     --  33.787

24/06/2002  05:02:02    --33.609    --     33.609       -- 33.610      -- 33.608

I'm a beginner in R, so this is pretty rough for me and I would be verv happy about suggestions or proposed solutions. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's easier to help you if you make your question reproducible including data and your code which can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Have a look at https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?

Answer (score 1):

1.Creating an example data set:

```
df <- structure(list(Sensor = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L),
                     Time = c("24/06/2002 05:02:01", "24/06/2002 05:02:01", "24/06/2002 05:02:01", "24/06/2002 05:02:01",
                              "24/06/2002 05:02:02", "24/06/2002 05:02:02", "24/06/2002 05:02:02","24/06/2002 05:02:02"),
                     Temp = c(33.855, 33.827, 33.104, 33.787, 33.609, 33.609, 33.61, 33.608)),
                row.names = c(NA, -8L),
                class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

2.Suggested solution using `tidyr` `pivot_wider`, a function that does **exactly** what you want ;)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Sensor, values_from = Temp, names_prefix="Sensor")
```

This Returns:

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 5
>   Time                Sensor1 Sensor2 Sensor3 Sensor4
>   <chr>                 <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
> 1 24/06/2002 05:02:01    33.9    33.8    33.1    33.8
> 2 24/06/2002 05:02:02    33.6    33.6    33.6    33.6
> ```

P.S. Actually there is no reason to use `dplyr` syntax, so here is the solution using only `tidyr::pivot_wider`:

```
pivot_wider(df, names_from = Sensor, values_from = Temp, names_prefix="Sensor")
```

## Edit

Removed accidental dependency on `data.table`

Comment: @r2evans Thanks, I seem to have forgotten that fread is not a base function ;)